# Fit container inside element with table layout

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need to fit a container inside a table cell. Currently, I am unable to do so, and the container only shows when I manually set its height.

Here it is a fiddle showing the issue.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13ug

If I set the container height to (say, 300), the container is displayed. However, I would like the container to automatically fit the colspan/rowspan and resize according to the table.

Could I please get some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will auto size the container to fill 100% of the cell height - even if the cell height increases.

```
initComponent: function() {
      var me = this;
        var tester2 = Ext.create("Ext.container.Container");
        Ext.apply(tester2, {
            height: "100%",
            layout: "fit",
            style:"background-color: red",
            colspan: 5,
            rowspan: 2,
        });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It seems that this overwrites the "rowspan". If I try to add another container and I set its rowspan to be half of the red one, the height would be wrong. I updated the fiddle to reflect this test.